# Strange pygame coordinates while in fullscreen

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, coordinates, fullscreen

I have written an app using pygame on a raspberry pi with touchscreen display. It works totally fine in windowed mode but it acts completely strange as soon as I switch to fullscreen mode. None of my touches (clicks) return a rational x and y, and they are usually returned as 799 and 479 (the downright corner of screen) after a couple of clicks. What can I do to fix the problem?

The fullscreen resolution for my screen is 800x480, I have to mention I do not have this problem while working on a desktop computer, and it only occurs when using the touchscreen input. Here is the related part of the code:

```
import pygame, time, math, os
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit

pygame.init()        
pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
pygame.mouse.set_pos(0, 0)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 480))
```

It works fine with this but when I switch to fullscreen:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

it will detect every click in the ending pixel of the screen. The strange thing is, when I place objects (e.g.buttons) on the main screen, they are being placed correctly at the right coordinates, but I cannot click on them since the returned coordinates from the touchscreen input are not correct.

Comment: Could you show us some initialization code for creating your pygame window? Are you passing (800, 500) as the size to `pygame.display.set_mode`? What is the resolution of your screen?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What an interesting problem! I just tested some of this code using my touchscreen on my Windows laptop (for once!) and it runs into some strange issues as well, so you are not alone! It seems to me, at least, that **only** whenever I hide my mouse cursor using `pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)` in combination with the `pygame.FULLSCREEN` flag do I get issues with my `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` events returning incorrect mouse positions. Making the cursor visible fixes this, but is obviously annoying for touchscreens. The solution (really a hack) I came up with is to use a borderless window that simulates a fullscreen mode instead by being positioned at the top-left corner of the screen. Here is the code; let me know if it works for you:

```
import pygame, time, math, sys, os

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "{0},{1}".format(0, 0)
pygame.init()        
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.NOFRAME)
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print(event.pos)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
```

That being said, I am curious to know **why** it does not work with the `pygame.FULLSCREEN` flag. If anyone can offer some insight on this for either pygame or SDL1.2, that would be much appreciated...

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think this is completely giving me the user experience I need, alongside with correct coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on: https://github.com/garthvh/pitftmenu

Fix Pygame on Debian Jessie

The package `"libsdl1.2-15-10"`, which ships with Debian Jessie, breaks pygame. To make it work we have to revert back to `"libsdl1.2-15-5"` from Wheezy.

The quickest way is to comment everything out in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and temporarily add:

```
deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
```

Import the corresponding keys:

```
deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
gpg -a --export 9165938D90FDDD2E | sudo apt-key add -
```

Remove the offending package and replace it with the working one:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get remove libsdl1.2debian python-pygame

apt-get install libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-mixer1.2 libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libsdl1.2debian libsmpeg0 python-pygame

sudo apt-mark hold libsdl1.2debian
```

Restore `"/etc/apt/sources.list"` to it's original state.

That's it. Pygame is fixed :-)